# How to do a vertical averaging of multiple ROC plots in R?

Tags: r, average, roc

I have 10 ROC separately in 10 individual excels. Each excels looks like the following

```
         cut    fpr         tpr
         Inf    0           0
-0.054137294    0.037037037 0.382352941
-0.148727463    0.074074074 0.382352941
-0.230797569    0.333333333 0.794117647
-0.407457844    0.740740741 0.882352941
-0.502048013    0.777777778 0.911764706
-0.58411812     0.777777778 0.970588235
```

Could anyone suggest me a way to do a vertical averaging in R, with the 10 ROC plots to get a graph plot like this
[image]
I checked the ROCR document, but it's not clear to me that how will I give my 10 ROCs as an input to plot the average ROC.

```
perf <- performance(pred,"tpr","fpr")
plot(perf,col="grey82",lty=3)
plot(perf,lwd=3,avg="vertical",spread.estimate="boxplot",add=TRUE)
```

Comment: Have you looked into the ROCR package? I think it might be able to do it

Comment: Yes I did, But it was not clearly given for multiple ROC plots. I have updated the question.